# uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CanCan (NameError) in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I've using nginx + unicorn at production

And I've got following error at log/unicorn.log but it's work fine at localhost (in both environments development and production)

```
I, [2012-07-01T19:20:39.905978 #15422]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2012-07-01T19:20:40.526582 #15418] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CanCan (NameError)
```

for line

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
```

I have gem 'cancan' in [Gemfile](https://github.com/ck3g/link_manager/blob/master/Gemfile#L20) (below gem 'rails'). Cancan gem is installed. I've tried both versions 1.6.7 and 1.6.8

```
current$ bundle exec gem list cancan

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cancan (1.6.7)

current$ bundle exec rails -v
Rails 3.2.3

current$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]

current$ bundle exec rails c production
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p125 :001 > CanCan
 => CanCan 
1.9.3p125 :002 >
```

What can be wrong with my configuration?

**upd:** 
`require 'cancan'` in `application_controller` cause error `No such file to load -- cancan (LoadError)`

[My Gemfile](https://github.com/ck3g/link_manager/blob/master/Gemfile#L20)

Comment: please post your gemfile. how are you requiring your gems? it looks like it's not properly required. does a 'require "cancan"' in your application controller help?

Comment: There was link to my Gemfile but I duplicate it again. `require 'cancan'` doesn't helped my. How can I properly require it? The problem is what it's works at localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `unicorn` doesn't load new gems on restart.

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_<project_name> stop
/etc/init.d/unicorn_<project_name> start
```

Fix the problem

Comment: Thanks! I've been scratching my head over this since I started using Unicorn. Previously I had to reboot the server for it to work again.